# Metal around wall register boot for trim

Tags: drywall, walls, ducts, register

Below are two images of what im talking about. Around the duct boot for the wall register is a metal box to make up for the difference between the wall and where the trim ends. What is it called and where can i find it?

Thank you for your time.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they're made anymore, but I heard them called Register Mounts, Extensions & Collars. I looked for replacements a few times & ended up with nothing to end up wire brushing them back to bare & spray painting them, good as new.

If no-one else here answers or has an avenue to get any. You can make your own quite easily & of much better quality...in the size that you need, which might be the real problem. I'd suggest Aluminum Angle for it's workability & corrosion resistance, but you can go with steel or C-channel or J-channel.

You'd probably need about a 4' length for each one & can either attach the last corner with a tab on the inside (not on the outside like the picture) or use a corner brace with countersunk (if desired or needed) screw, bolt or pop-rivet face holes.

[image: Alum angle]

Comment: Ended up cleaning it off and reusing it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Great Job! It should be good for many more decades.